# How do I change a product variaton through an image field?

Tags: commerce

Using Drupal Commerce you can set fields in the product entity which can function as attribute selection fields. The visitor can use them to switch the variations of a product.

I created a field called SIZE which allows the visitor to switch the variations of a product. This works fine. Now I need to allow to change the variation by clicking in a image of the variation. See my capture to get the idea.

I create an image field and set it to 1 value, but the "Attribute field settings" area didn't show up. In this area you can check "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms."

I thought this module could help, but as far as I see it is not useful for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Drupal Commerce, but to output an option field into a rich menu, you'll have to use javascript. Just like you've created the Size field, create a field called "Color" and add the options "brown", "red", "green", etc... and on the front-end, have javascript replace the select field with images. Then, in the background, have javascript select the color based on what the user clicks.

Comment: One aspect of your setup you did not say.  Are you using a view to display this or is this a node display for the products?

Comment: It´s a node display of the product.

Comment: I think here you need to add some css 3 or javascript. Means display the radio buttons and change radio button as images.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to use an image field as a product attribute, it's more applicable that you would use radio buttons and use JS to change the view of the button as mentioned by @SumitMadan. Without trying, you might be able to create a colour taxonomy, add an image field to the taxonomy, and then add the taxonomy to your product display, you should then be able to use some JS to replace the text with an image

Comment: Please say how you make image changing on attribute change. I can't achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Commerce Fancy Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) along with [Field Extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_extractor) Module

This module provides:

- A formatter for reference fields
- A views field for reference fields (called "Field extracted from entity referenced through $field")

This module uses [field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) hook

> Returns a renderable array for the value of a single field in an
>   entity.
>
> The resulting output is a fully themed field with label and multiple
>   values.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea. I'll try it.